# Available record types on all profiles

Tags: record-type

I want to create a map in such a way that key contains profile name and values should be the available record types for that profile. When I am using isAvailable() method which is available on RecordtypeInfo class it is retrieving only for the logged in user. I am not able to understand how to frame that map. Any suggestions/help is more helpful for me.

Comment: could you please post your code.

Comment: for(RecordtypeInfo rtype : Account.sobjecttype.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()){         if(rtype.isAvailable(){.         Pmap.put(userinfo.getprofileid(),rtype.name}.    This is returning with the current user, now my requirements are enhanced to create a map with all the profile names as key and which record types they have access to as values. Any suggestions/help is appreciated

Comment: please use [edit] to amend your post with code

Comment: note also that when the transaction executes, it is in the context of the running user so why is it important to know available rectypes by profile?